# Javascript, Jquery and jade: Dynamic forms not showing up in all the instances of relevant elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

I'm trying to generate dynamic form and show it when someone hit reply in comment section.

So,

First generating a form like below using Jquery.

```
script(type='text/javascript').
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var cVariable = !{JSON.stringify(data1)};
            var userEmail = !{JSON.stringify(data.userEmail1)};
            var serviceID = !{JSON.stringify(data._id)};

            if(cVariable == 1){
                var $myform = $('<form/>', {
                action: '/services/shoutOutReplyAdd', 
                method: 'post',
                name: 'reply-form' 

                });

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'text',
                name: 'reply',
                id: 'formAddReply', 
                placeholder: 'reply'
                }));

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'hidden',
                id: 'userEmail1',
                name: 'userEmail1',
                value: userEmail
                }));

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'hidden',
                id: 'serviceID',
                name: 'serviceID',
                value: serviceID
                }));

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'submit',
                id: 'btn',
                value: 'Post reply'
                }));

                $("#reply-comment-form").append($myform);

            }


        });

$(function(){
            $('.reply-comment').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).next('#reply-comment-form').show();
            });
        });
```

Second step is to specify HTML/Jade for the main body. I'm getting message values from the server and want to display a reply form when user clicks a reply text. Loop is executed three times.

```
each i in data.reply
            p #{i.msg}
            a(id='' class = 'reply-comment' href='') Reply
            #reply-comment-form         
        hr      
        br
```

Also node that, in CSS, I have setup like below

```
  #reply-comment-form{ display:none; }
```

I also have the JQ function that when clicking the anchor element text, it shows the form. Here is the code for it.

```
$(function(){
            $('.reply-comment').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).next('#reply-comment-form').show();
            });
        });
```

When, I check the generated HTML, I only see form is assigned only for first instance of the "reply-comment-form" div element.

There are three comments in the DB, so I should see three instances of the form. However, I'm only seeing one instance.

Just another piece of information, code to generate a form and code to click the anchor element are both inside a common `script(type='text/javascript').`  block.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please correct your title, it has nothing to do the the actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creating the form inside the click function did the trick.

```
$('.reply-comment').on('click', function(e){

                var $myform = $('<form/>', {
                action: '/services/shoutOutReplyAdd', 
                method: 'POST',
                name: 'reply-form' 

                });

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'text',
                name: 'reply',
                id: 'formAddReply', 
                placeholder: 'reply'
                }));

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'hidden',
                id: 'userEmail1',
                name: 'userEmail1',
                value: userEmail
                }));

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'hidden',
                id: 'serviceID',
                name: 'serviceID',
                value: serviceID
                }));

                $myform.append($("<input/>", {
                type: 'submit',
                id: 'btn',
                value: 'Post reply'
                }));

                $(this).append($myform);
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).next('#reply-comment-form').show();
            });
```